# azure app insights alert to monitor health in a azure bot framework project

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-application-insights

I need to configure an alert for an azure appservice resource where I have a bot created from the Microsoft bot framework, this is integrated into azure app insights.

My question is what parameter should I take to configure an azure app insights alert so that I can measure the health of my bot application properly and that it is within good practices?

[image]

Comment: I think you can choose to use heartbeat sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, if you wanna alert on machines that are not available, you can set application insights in your code and it will [send heartbeat by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#using-applicationinsightsserviceoptions). And you can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to add telemetry to your bot.（Mainly add `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.ApplicationInsights.Core` NuGet package and modify `ConfigureServices()` method in `Startup.cs` and some other settings）

After that, your bot program will send heartbeat, you can see details in [app insights custom metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64909025) via `customMetrics | where name == "HeartbeatState"`. Then you can [create alert rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log) on yourself.

[image]

Comment: exactly @Tiny-wa, I was seeing some filters to detect WaterfallStart, but this one that you mention to me is the one that resolved me to be able to measure the availability in the bot resource, which was what I was looking for.

Comment: That's great, thanks for your response sir!